# Working with Times and Dates in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I have a form that is using [timepicker addon](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) to select date and time.

My model have a column:

```
datetime :start_time
```

When the forms get submitted params hash has:

```
params[:start_time] #= '08/31/2014 10:50' as a string
```

**What would be a best way to save it in to the database as a datetime format?**

I don't fully understand the way how the time is handled, localizations, time zones etc.

When I tried to save it with out formatting, as a string, I am getting **argument out of reach** error. When I created new **Time** instance passing params[:start_date] as an argument it was saved as:

```
0008-01-01 00:01:15 UTC
```

TY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try tweaking the `timepicker` so the client-side will give rails the desired formatting.

This way you only need to config your `timepicker` once and you won't need to parse the time in the server side every time

Something like:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#timePicker').datetimepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm ss z'
    });
});
```

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hdgyhfgu/1/) for a demo

Comment: This method has one more advantage over @ISO4 one. I doesn't require to check if params[:start_time] is present. In a situation when params[:start_time] is nil(testing validations), strptime throws exception invalid date.

Answer (score 1):

you could write something like this, for getting correct date from your string:

```
date_time = DateTime.strptime(params[:start_time], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
date_time.to_s #=> "2014-08-31T10:50:00+00:00"
```

Comment: Thank you for a suggestion mate. Nimir's answer is a more general one. I might be using datetimepicker in few other places in the app.

Comment: @Nimir shows how set date format in `datetimepicker`, when I wrote how parse your date string in ruby